# Wrong result in multiplying in 8086 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, x86-16

The program must calculate the following:

in `VP` array , each index will have the value of `Multiplying V1[INDEX] WITH V2[INDEX]`
in `VPROD` array , the program `ADDS` all the Values of Array `VP`

Example:

```
VP = { V1[0]*V2[0] , V1[1]*V2[1] , V1[2]*V2[2] , V1[3]*V2[3] ,V1[4]*V2[4] }
VPROD = { VP[0] + VP[1] + VP[2] + VP[3] + VP[4] }
```

The problem is that when the result is bigger than 16 bits (a word), it **does not** give the right results. But when the result is smaller than 16 bits, it gives the right result.

I thought about **Carry** and fixed my code, but still it gives me bad results.

My code:

```
    dseg segment

    v1 DW 255,5,255,9,21
    v2 DW 4,4,255,13,5
    vprod DW 10 DUP (0)
    vp DW 10 DUP (?)
    N DB 5
    dseg ends

    sseg segment stack
            dw 100h dup(?)
    sseg ends

    cseg segment
    assume  ds:dseg,cs:cseg,ss:sseg
    start:      mov ax,dseg
                MOV DS,AX
            MOV SI,0
            MOV CX,0
            MOV CL,N
            MOV DI, 0
LOVP:       MOV AX,v1[si]    
            MUL v2[si]
            MOV vp[di],AX
            MOV vp[di+2],DX
            ADD SI,2
            ADD DI,4
            LOOP LOVP
            MOV CX,0
            MOV CL,N
            MOV SI,0
            MOV DI,0
LOVPROD:    MOV AX,vp[SI]
            ADD vprod[DI],AX
            ADC VPROD[DI+2],0
            ADD SI,2
            LOOP LOVPROD

    SOF:
                mov ah,4ch
            int 21h
    cseg ends
    end start
```

Comment: What result DO you get? Do you have a debugger you can step through your code with?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat let's say I have this two arrays (LOOK AGAIN , I UPDATED THE VALUES) ,, the result should be : 102EF 
what i get is : 03DE

Comment: What assembler are you using?  In the syntax I'm used to one line should be 'mov cl,[N]'  instead of 'mov cl,n'

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting a 32 bit result from the multiply, you should use 4 bytes for every element of the `vp` array. You will need to use a separate index for that, and of course store the high word at offset +2 instead of +1. For the summation part, you should add up both low and high words.
Fixed code for the multiplication could look like:

```
            MOV DI, 0
LOVP:       MOV AX,v1[si]    
            MUL v2[si]
            MOV vp[di],AX
            MOV vp[di+2],DX
            ADD SI,2
            ADD DI,4
            LOOP LOVP
```

I trust you can do the summation yourself, using `ADD` and `ADC`.

**UPDATE**:
Since your post says you want to sum the `vp` array, I don't see why you expect the result in another array (`vprod`). The sum is a scalar value, do something like:

```
            MOV SI, 0
            MOV AX, 0
            MOV DX, 0
LOVPROD:    ADD AX,vp[SI]
            ADC DX,vp[SI+2]
            ADD SI,4
            LOOP LOVPROD
```

The result will be in `DX`:`AX`

Also, for the `LOOP` to work properly, you should put the number of iterations into `CX`, not `0` as you are doing.